# Golang - flag.Arg(0) returns index 1 instead of index 0 of arguments passed by exec.cmd

Tags: go

I currently have something in my `bar` app that looks like this

```
flag.Parse()
str := flag.Arg(0)
fmt.println(str)
```

Now in my foo app I have something like this

```
var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Cmd{
        Path:   c.Path,
        Args:   c.Args,
        Env:    c.Env,
        Stdin:  bytes.NewReader(b),
        Stdout: &stdout,
        Stderr: &stderr,
    }

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Now in the above c.Args = [1,2,3]

foo program attempts to call into bar program and bar displays 2
How do I make bar display 1 instead.

I know `flag.parse` ignores the first parameter. How do I tell read the first parameter (index 0) using flag.Arg()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cmd.Args` includes the command name.  `flag.Arg(0)` is the first argument after the command name and flags.

Fix by adding the command name to `Cmd.Args`.

```
cmd := exec.Cmd{
    Path:   c.Path,
    Args:   append([]string{c.Path}, c.Args...),
    Env:    c.Env,
    Stdin:  bytes.NewReader(b),
    Stdout: &stdout,
    Stderr: &stderr,
}
```